# Can control a JavaScript code's accessible tags or DOC?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I don't know any thing about JavaScript and want  to know...
In a html page we have  script A (in  tag) which A is in `<div>` tags.

How we can prevent accesses of JavaScript A to other or special tags?
Can apply this by another JavaScript in separated tag?

for example in this page:

```
<html>
...
<tag1>
<script> A</script>
</tag1>
....
<tag2> ... </tag2>
...
</html>
```

We want script A can access only to  content.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. If the element exists in the DOM, the javascript can locate it.

Comment: Not in an easy way. What is your reason to want that? I guess there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can load a page from a different domain into an `<iframe>`, JavaScript shouldn't be allowed to access that because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Thank you...
In my work this tag maybe Disassemble page style.
For prevent from that i used <DIV> tag. So Can I Control Or at last disable script A by another script?
best regards

Comment: No, you can't "*disable*" scripts (via JS). What is executed stays executed. You only can disable functionality if the script offers a public "API" module (global variable) to do that.

Comment: Thank you for answer.. so in another way if we have javaScript in page and may be used Doc in it's code. so if I move some tags' into <iframe>, can affect that javaScript execution? and iframe's content load from same domain.Can we set another domain for it?

Comment: No, you need to use another domain so no javascript in the parent page can access the embedded document.

Comment: srcdoc [http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-srcdoc]
 is a solution for this? what about CSP(content Security policy)?